# When to instantiate single instance backbone model using requirejs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I am using RequireJS with backbone and I am wondering when should I return an instance and when I should return a class definition.

For example, I have a model `that I need only one instance of it` and I need only one instance for it. Should I instantiate it in the RequireJS model module or in the appView initialize?

```
  define([
        'Underscore',
        'Backbone'
    ], function(_, Backbone) {
        var TermModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
            defaults: {
                term: ''
            }
        });


return new TermModel(); //<-----------new OR not??
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First you should shim underscore in the config file, check this for reference http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config

Second, if you need to instanciate this model only one time then this is fine. Though keep in mind you will have less control over the instantiation time, therefore I wouldn't recommand it.

Comment: What do u mean by “less controlt over the instantiation time“? And what others ways I have in order to get access to the model in case I don't instantiate it in the requirejs module?

Comment: I could be wrong but i guess imagine instantiating that model inside a nested view or something - that case kept me from not instantiating models straight away.

Comment: @Varinder: In case I create model instance in my appView.js, how can I get access to that single instance of the model?

Comment: Im not sure if i got the question right, storing that new instance inside a variable will do, something like var model = new Model({//some options}). model.someProperty // accessing that single instance. The benifit i feel with this approach is that now you can create slight variations of the same model, something like var model2 = new Model({//some other options}). model2.someOtherProperty.